# C++ Substracting adjacent elements in a vector

Tags: c++, vector

I am writing a code to subtract the adjacent elements of a vector and enter the answer into a new vector.  However, my code isn't working.  What exactly is wrong with it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int length;
    vector<int>values;
    vector<int>values2;

    cout << "Enter the length of the vector";
    cin  >> length;

    values[0]=1; values[1]=2; values[2]=3; values[3]=4; values[4]=5;

    for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
        cout<<"Enter the " << i <<"th element of the vector";
        cin >> values[i];
    }

    for (int i=0; i<length-1; i++)
    {
        values2[i]=values[i+1]-values[0];

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When something "is not working", try to be as precise as possible. Does it compile ? Does it print not the output that you expected ? Does it crash ? Give us proof that you really searched by yourself before asking for help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to size the vectors accordingly before accessing elements. You can do that on construction, or using `resize`.

`vector<int>values(5/*pre-size for 5 elements*/);` and similar for `values2` would fix your problem.

Currently your program behaviour is undefined.

If you want to subtract *adjacent* elements, then shouldn't you have `values2[i]=values[i+1]-values[i];`?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and yes you're right about the substraction of adjacent elements. It all works now.

Answer (score 0):

The line of code:

```
values2[i]=values[i+1]-values[0];
```

will take the looked-at element away from the first element each time.
Did you mean:

```
values2[i]=values[i+1]-values[i];
```

?

Comment: @Gordkn, yes that's what I meant.